# need to get a subsequent record with a specific value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have the following table :

```
        Dt          Status
05.23.2019 10:00:00   A
05.23.2019 11:00:00   B
05.23.2019 12:00:00   B
05.23.2019 13:00:00   D
05.23.2019 14:00:00   A
05.23.2019 15:00:00   B
05.23.2019 16:00:00   C
05.23.2019 17:00:00   D
05.23.2019 18:00:00   A
```

For each status A i need to get the next status D. The result should be like this :

```
Status1   Status2  Dt1                  Dt2
A         D        05.23.2019 10:00:00  05.23.2019 13:00:00
A         D        05.23.2019 14:00:00  05.23.2019 17:00:00
A         null     05.23.2019 18:00:00  null
```

I have my own solution based on cross/outer apply , In terms of performance i need solution without cross/outer apply.

Comment: Can you share cross join query

Comment: What should happen if you have the "sequence" `AAD` or `ADD`? Which rows should be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here along with some pivot logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY Dt) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Status IN ('A', 'D')
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'A' THEN Status END) AS Status1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'D' THEN Status END) AS Status2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'A' THEN Dt END) AS Dt1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'D' THEN Dt END) AS Dt2
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```

[image]

### Demo

The idea here is to generate a row number sequence along your entire table, for each separate `Status` value (A or D).  Then, aggregate by that row number sequence to bring the A and D records together.

Comment: i am sorry , it doesn't work as i need , when there are a few of the same status appear consistently , like A,A,A or D,D,D

Comment: This answers the question you actually asked.  If you have some other problem, then you should either edit your question, or ask a new one.

Comment: This solution seems to produce incorrect results now. It seems that the OP updated the question and included additional A-records after the last D-record in the sample data. If you can get your CTE-solution to work with that, that would be great. (It would probably be better than my somewhat more complex answer at least.)

Comment: The OP should _not_ change the question after others have already answered.  I have rolled back.

Comment: Yes. I saw it and I was initially shocked. But I understand now. And I agree.

Answer (score 1):

As result columns `Status1` and `Status2` always seem to be "A" and "D" respectively, I omitted them in my result.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    [Dt] SMALLDATETIME,
    [Status] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @Data ([Dt], [Status]) VALUES
    ('2019-05-23 10:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2019-05-23 11:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2019-05-23 12:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2019-05-23 13:00:00', 'D'),
    ('2019-05-23 14:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2019-05-23 15:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2019-05-23 16:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2019-05-23 17:00:00', 'D'),
    ('2019-05-23 18:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2019-05-23 19:00:00', 'D'),
    ('2019-05-23 20:00:00', 'D'),
    ('2019-05-23 21:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2019-05-23 22:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2019-05-23 23:00:00', 'A');

SELECT
    D.[Dt] AS [Dt1],
    [LastDBeforeNextA].[Dt] AS [Dt2]
FROM
    @Data AS D
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) [Dt]
                 FROM @Data
                 WHERE [Status] = 'A' AND [Dt] > D.[Dt]
                 ORDER BY [Dt]) AS [NextA]
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) [Dt]
                 FROM @Data
                 WHERE [Status] = 'D' AND [Dt] < [NextA].[Dt] AND [Dt] > D.[Dt]
                 ORDER BY [Dt] DESC) AS [LastDBeforeNextA]
WHERE
    D.[Status] = 'A' AND
    ([NextA].[Dt] > [LastDBeforeNextA].[Dt] OR ([LastDBeforeNextA].[Dt] IS NULL AND [NextA].[Dt] IS NULL))
```

It initially gets all records from the table where status is 'A' (using expression `D.[Status] = 'A'` in the WHERE-clause).

For each record found, it joins the date of the next record with status A (table expression with alias `NextA`) and the date of the last record with status D that comes right before the next A-record but after the current A-record (table expression with alias `LastDBeforeNextA`).

Results are valid when a D-record is found (expression `[NextA].[Dt] > [LastDBeforeNextA].[Dt]` in the WHERE-clause) or when there is no D-record yet (expression `[LastDBeforeNextA].[Dt] IS NULL` in the WHERE-clause). In the latter case, you need to get the latest A-record, however (expression `[NextA].[Dt] IS NULL` in the WHERE-clause), since there can be multiple A-records after the last D-record.